# Javascript: Find 2nd occurrence(last) of largest number & return same index in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has two occurrences of the largest number. I want to get the 2nd occurrence of the largest number, in the findSum array, so index[3], and then return index[3] of another array, numbers.

```
findSum = [49, 81, 81, 64];

Function findLargest(arr) { 
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
return largest;  
};
console.log(findLargest(findSum));

var numbers = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', 
'4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];
```

Right now I'm using Math.max to find the largest, and I think I am just returning the first occurrence, index[2] of 81. Side note: How do you check which 81 is returning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `4556-4242-9283-2260` is not a `Number`

Comment: Yes, I converted it to a number and reduced it. The findSum array is the result of that @Rayon

Comment: in arrays index 0 is position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) for that, which would return `index[2]` as arrays are zero-based.

```
var findSum = [49, 81, 81, 64];

function findLastLargest(arr) {
    var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
    return arr.lastIndexOf(largest);
}

var numbers = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972',
    '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'
]

console.log(numbers[findLastLargest(findSum)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will find the largest number in the array and the last index of the largest number in the array.

```
function findLastIndexOfLargestNumber(array){
    var maxNum = Number.MIN_VALUE;
    var maxNumIndex = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var currentNumber = array[i];
        if(currentNumber >= maxNum){
            maxNum = currentNumber;
            maxNumIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return { maxNum : maxNum, maxNumIndex : maxNumIndex };
}

console.log(findLastIndexOfLargestNumber([49, 81, 81, 64]));
```

Comment: I plugged in your code. I get: Object {maxNum: 81, maxNumIndex: 2}

Comment: Yeah, it returns the largest number as well as the index it was stored at. See https://repl.it/CWLz

Comment: Aah, got it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf` function of array.

```
findSum = [49, 81, 81, 64];

Function findLargest(arr) { 
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
return largest;  
};
console.log(findSum.lastIndexOf(findLargest(findSum)));

var numbers = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', 
'4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];
```

Answer (score 0):

One shortcut.

```js
var findSum = [49, 81, 81, 64],
    numbers = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972',
    '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'],
     number = numbers[findSum.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...findSum))];
console.log(number);
```